# How to Optimize google maps api calls for mobile apps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

How can we reduce Google Maps api calls??
in one of our app (similar like uber) we are using Google directions api to plot two points(source and destination) and dynamic path between them,
so we have to update this path every-time in 4-5 seconds ,
In 2 months mostly 1.2 million requests are getting generated for directions api , and google maps charging almost $5k-8k per month which is very high. Any mechanism to optimise the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the call every 4-5 seconds.  Why are you doing that anyway?  The location doesn't change that much in 4-5 seconds, it may not change at all (they may be stuck at a light).  Instead, track their GPS location and update it only every few hundred meters.  That's a good step one.  A next step after that would be to look at the actual route data returned by the API, and use the GPS data to see if the user is following the route, and update only if the user significantly deviates from it.  This is also how Maps and GPS devices work-  you'll notice that deviating from a route takes some time for the device to notice, and then it recalculates.

To do the latter-  the DirectionsResult object holds a set of legs.  Each leg is the directions to a single waypoint (so if you're just going directly to one place, it will be a single leg).  Inside that is a series of steps.  Each step has start and end GPS coordinates.  If you're moving in the general direction from start to end GPS coordinates, no need to recompute.  Unless your route is extremely curved, this would be good enough.  There's also paths within a step that provides a series of points along the step, you can probably use that if it exists to provide more exact navigation along complex steps.